# How to issue a 'find' or 'where' that raises a RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

When I call a find with an id, it becomes a targeted find, and will throw an error RecordNotFound.

```
Foo::Bar.find(123) # RecordNotFound if no Bar with id 123 exists.
```

But when I call that with conditions, I get nil if not found:

```
Foo::Bar.find(:first, :conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", name.downcase ])
```

I want such a conditional search to raise an error too. I know I can do:

```
Foo::Bar.find_by_name!("CocktailBar") #=> raises Recordnotfount if not not found.
```

But that has only really simple conditions. Mine need a little more complexity; actually something like:

```
Foo.Bar.select{ |pm| pm.name.downcase =~ /cocktail/}.first
```

And, if nothing is found, I want it to raise the RecordNotFound error. Is that possible at all? Or should I simply add some code to check against nil? and if nil? raise the error myself? And if so, how do I do that in Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final paragraph is what you need to do. Either check against nil, or raise the exceptions yourself. To raise the exception yourself, do the following:

```
Foo::Bar.find(:first, :conditions => [ "lower(name) = ?", name.downcase ]) || raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

Answer (score 47):

In the last snippet of code you are actually fetching all records from DB and then doing `select` on a Ruby array. It has nothing to do with `ActiveRecord`, so you can do whatever you like to raise exception manually, either use the code suggested by Douglas, or `if`, or `unless` etc. But it seems that you don't quite understand what your code does. Your `select {...}` is not translated into SQL `SELECT ... WHERE(...)`.

If you need an exception raised automatically by `ActiveRecord` query, use this:

```
Foo::Bar.where([ "lower(name) = ?", name.downcase ]).first!
```

The equivalent bang methods exist for find_by methods as well, for example `Foo::Bar.find_by_name!(name)`

Comment: Never knew about the `first!` method, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @lulalala Thanks for extending my answer. I didn't care to mention the `find_by` methods because the question author explicitly says he knows them and the question is not quite about this.

Comment: @RocketR I just realized it in mentioned in question now. I guess I was focusing on the question title.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone coming across this question, now you have the method `find_by!` 
that does exactly what the OP asked for the `find` case.

example:

```
Foo::Bar.find_by!(name: "CocktailBar")
```

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by%21