# How can I have Rails 4 generate an exception when a .find() fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the production environment configuration I can't seem to find a configuration parameter to tell the server that when an ActiveRecord `Class.find()` throws an exception, that it should really be an exception.  In development mode, it throws an **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound** exception, but in production it rescues it and renders a **404**.  I seem to remember this being something you could turn on/off?  I would rather not monkey patch the 404 which is the only solution I have seen so far.

The .find(id) method should be used whenever you want an exception to be thrown if the id cannot be found as described in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ids).  If you don't want an exception to be thrown, you should use .find_by_id(id).

Comment: I assume that "Class" is a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base, and it is throwing something like ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, but it would be good for you to provide details like that.

Comment: Is it in production mode? Do you see the same behavior in development mode? In production mode rails does not show stack trace on browser since it is supposed to be open to the world... and you don't want to show your application internals to the world.

Comment: @Eternal-Learner I'm not interested in showing the stack trace, just generating the exception.  The user should see a 500 error page.

Comment: It is a rails standard behavior to return 404 for ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. You may be able to rescue it yourself in your controller and instead `render :status => 500`. BTW http status code 404 stands for "not found". and 500 stands for "internal error". S0 in my opinion 404 is appropriate.

Comment: @Eternal-Learner I would agree with you but there is a difference between .find() and .find_by_id().  .find() throws an exception while .find_by_id() returns nothing. Also, development mode throws an exception and does not render a 404.

Comment: `find_by_id` or `find_by_*` helpers in general mean "get me first record that match xxx". If no record matches, that is what AR returns - an empty set. On the other hand `find` helper means "get me a record with the id xxx". And if AR does not find a record with id xxx, it replies back saying so "RecordNotFound".

Comment: However, `find_by_*!` will throw a RecordNotFound exception if no record matches the criteria.

Comment: Have you tried using rescue_from, like   rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616946/how-to-issue-a-find-or-where-that-raises-a-recordnotfound

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L26

adds a mapping

`'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'   => :not_found`

asking action_dispatch to rescue 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' with `:not_found` response.

Doing -
`YourAppName::Application.config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.delete('ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound')`

in your initializer might get what you're expecting.

Comment: I just gave this a shot, but still no exception is raised.  The log continues to just show I, "INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms".  Somewhere it has to be rescuing!